# Pairwise count of common elements in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape 5000, 9 and dtype int. I am trying to create an array of shape 5000, 5000 of dtype int that contains a count of shared elements in each pair of arrays.

I can accomplish this using itertools.combinations and a loop, but that approach is pretty slow (3-4 minutes on my machine), so I'm searching for a more efficient alternative. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

# create random array where row don't have duplicates
data = np.random.rand(5000, 9).argsort(axis=0)
counts = np.zeros((5000, 9), dtype=int)
for i, j in combinations(range(len(data)), 2):
    counts[i, j] = len(np.intersect1d(data[i], data[j]))
```

Comment: What is the range of the values in `data`?

Comment: There are between 100-200 unique integers in data and they range from 0 to 400.

Comment: I can make the range of values smaller (maybe down to 200 or so) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# sample data with 200 unique values
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.array([np.random.choice(np.arange(200), size=9, replace=False)
                 for _ in range(5000)]
               )

# identify the unique values:
uniques = np.unique(data)

# dummy for each row
a = (data[...,None] == uniques).sum(1)

# output
out = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',a,a)
```

Takes about 4.5s on my system.